# Wrong library loads wrong function in manually-generated PE 64-bit executable

Tags: assembly, nasm, portable-executable

I have 64 bit manually-generated PE executable. I need to load two libraries `kernel32.dll` and `user.dll`. It gives the first error.

[image]

If I have only one library (this would be `kernel32.dll`) I get the second error. Is there any way to get another error.

[image]

Is there any way to get all libraries correct? Bear in mind that code is ported from 32bit executable. You can see the code below.

```
bits 64
BASE                equ 400000h
ALIGNMENT equ 512
%define SECTALIGN  4096
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE   equ -11
NULL                equ 0

%define ROUND(v, a) (((v + a - 1) / a) * a)
%define ALIGNED(v) (ROUND(v, ALIGNMENT))
%define RVA(obj) (obj - BASE)

section header progbits start=0 vstart=BASE

mz_hdr:
    dw "MZ"                       ; DOS magic
    times 0x3a db 0               ; [UNUSED] DOS header
    dd RVA(pe_hdr)                ; address of PE header

pe_hdr:
    dw "PE",0                     ; PE magic + 2 padding bytes
    dw 0x8664                     ; i386 architecture
    dw 2                          ; two sections
    dd __POSIX_TIME__             ; [UNUSED] timestamp
    dd 0                          ; [UNUSED] symbol table pointer
    dd 0                          ; [UNUSED] symbol count
    dw OPT_HDR_SIZE               ; optional header size
    dw 0x0002                     ; characteristics: 32-bit, executable

opt_hdr:
    dw 0x020b                     ; optional header magic
    db 13,37                      ; [UNUSED] linker version
    dd ALIGNED(S_TEXT_SIZE)       ; [UNUSED] code size
    dd ALIGNED(S_IDATA_SIZE)      ; [UNUSED] size of initialized data
    dd 0                          ; [UNUSED] size of uninitialized data
    dd RVA(section..text.vstart)  ; entry point address
    dd RVA(section..text.vstart)  ; [UNUSED] base of code
    dd RVA(section..idata.vstart) ; [UNUSED] base of data
    dq BASE                       ; image base
    dd SECTALIGN                  ; section alignment
    dd ALIGNMENT                  ; file alignment
    dw 4,0                        ; [UNUSED] OS version
    dw 0,0                        ; [UNUSED] image version
    dw 4,0                        ; subsystem version
    dd 0                          ; [UNUSED] Win32 version
    dd RVA(the_end)               ; size of image
    dd ALIGNED(ALL_HDR_SIZE)      ; size of headers
    dd 0                          ; [UNUSED] checksum
    dw 3                          ; subsystem = console
    dw 0                          ; [UNUSED] DLL characteristics
    dq 0x0010000000000000                 ; [UNUSED] maximum stack size
    dq 0x0000100000000000                 ; initial stack size
    dq 0x0010000000000000                 ; maximum heap size
    dq 0x0000100000000000                 ; [UNUSED] initial heap size
    dd 0                          ; [UNUSED] loader flags
    dd 16                         ; number of data directory entries
    dd 0,0                        ; no export table
    dd RVA(import_table)          ; import table address
    dd IMPORT_TABLE_SIZE          ; import table size
    times 14 dd 0,0               ; no other entries in the data directories
OPT_HDR_SIZE equ $ - opt_hdr

sect_hdr_text:
    db ".text",0,0,0              ; section name
    dd ALIGNED(S_TEXT_SIZE)       ; virtual size
    dd RVA(section..text.vstart)  ; virtual address
    dd ALIGNED(S_TEXT_SIZE)       ; file size
    dd section..text.start        ; file position
    dd 0,0                        ; no relocations or debug info
    dw 0,0                        ; no relocations or debug info
    dd 0x60000020                 ; flags: code, readable, executable
    
sect_hdr_idata:
    db ".idata",0,0               ; section name
    dd ALIGNED(S_IDATA_SIZE)      ; virtual size
    dd RVA(section..idata.vstart) ; virtual address
    dd ALIGNED(S_IDATA_SIZE)      ; file size
    dd section..idata.start       ; file position
    dd 0,0                        ; no relocations or debug info
    dw 0,0                        ; no relocations or debug info
    dd 0xC0000040                 ; flags: data, readable, writeable

ALL_HDR_SIZE equ $ - $$

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; .text ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

section .text progbits follows=header align=ALIGNMENT vstart=BASE+SECTALIGN*1
s_text:
    
    ; set up stack frame for *lpBytesWritten
 
    ; push    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    ; call    [GetStdHandle]

    ; push    NULL
    ; push    buffer
    ; push    message_size
    ; push    message
    ; push    eax
    ; call    [WriteConsoleA]
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 40
    
    push 0
    call [ExitProcess]
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
S_TEXT_SIZE equ $ - s_text

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; .idata ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

section .idata progbits follows=.text align=ALIGNMENT vstart=BASE+SECTALIGN*2
s_idata:
; message db "Hello World!",0
; message_size equ $ - message
; buffer              resd 4
; buffer2             resb 64

import_table:
    ; import of kernel32.dll
    dd 0                        ; [UNUSED] read-only IAT
    dd 0                        ; [UNUSED] timestamp
    dd 0                        ; [UNUSED] forwarder chain
    dd RVA(N_kernel32)          ; library name
    dd RVA(IAT_kernel32)        ; IAT pointer
    ; import of user32.dll
    dd 0                        ; [UNUSED] read-only IAT
    dd 0                        ; [UNUSED] timestamp
    dd 0                        ; [UNUSED] forwarder chain
    dd RVA(N_user32)            ; library name
    dd RVA(IAT_user32)          ; IAT pointer
    ; terminator (empty item)
    times 5 dd 0
IMPORT_TABLE_SIZE: equ $ - import_table

IAT_kernel32:
    ExitProcess:      dd RVA(H_ExitProcess)
    GetStdHandle:     dd RVA(H_GetStdHandle)
    WriteConsoleA:    dd RVA(H_WriteConsoleA)
    dd 0
IAT_user32:
    MessageBoxA:      dd RVA(H_MessageBoxA)
    dd 0

                    align 4, db 0
N_kernel32:         db "kernel32.dll",0
                    align 4, db 0
N_user32:           db "user32.dll",0
                    align 2, db 0
H_MessageBoxA:      db 0,0,"MessageBoxA",0
                    align 2, db 0
H_GetStdHandle:     db 0,0,"GetStdHandle",0
                    align 2, db 0
H_WriteConsoleA:    db 0,0,"WriteConsoleA",0
                    align 2, db 0
H_ExitProcess:      db 0,0,"ExitProcess",0

S_IDATA_SIZE equ $ - s_idata


align ALIGNMENT, db 0
the_end:
```

Comment: You've got several challenges here.  Clearly, the first problem is that your .asm module is trying to to load MessageA from kernel32.dll, instead of (the correct library) user32.dll.  There are undoubtedly other problems, too.  SUGGESTION: Why don't you write a simple ".c" function that calls "Message()", "ExitProcess()", "GetStdHandle()" etc. and reverse-engineer it by compiling with [/Fa](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fa-fa-listing-file?view=vs-2019)?

Comment: The problem is that my task is to build a program using custom PE32+ executable. Otherwise I agree that it wouldn't be my first choice too.

Comment: Your immediate problem is that the assembly code isn't generating the correct binary .obj.  "/Fa" should help guide you with fixing your code.  With any luck, you might then be "home free" regarding your PE 32+ .exe.  Give it a shot.

Comment: @paulsm4: The OP forgot to mention, but they're building with `nasm -fbin`, not creating a `.obj` for the linker.  That's why the PE32+ headers are there in the source with `dd` and so on, and why they need `bits 64`.  (I recognized some of this from [their previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64164559/image-base-comes-out-wrong-in-manually-generated-pe-headers-for-a-64-bit-executa) where that was explicit)

Comment: Separate things: `default rel` would be a good idea; absolute addressing modes aren't helpful.   More importantly, you're using the wrong calling convention.  Windows x64 passes the first 4 args in registers, not on the stack.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: I'm confused.  I thought the OP was simply porting some 32-bit code, with the intent on creating a standard 64-bit Windows .exe, which I believe is a PE32+ format image.  I also thought he could use nasm to create an .obj, and use the standard MSVS tools to link it.  Q: Is this off-base?  Q: If he succeeds, will he load the 64-bit versions of user32.dll and kernel32.dll in \windows\system32?  Or the 32-bit versions in \Windows\SysWOW64? If the former, why is he specifying 32-bit/x86 stuff in     his .asm code?  Q: Why is he loading kernel32.dll instead of user32.dll?

Comment: @paulsm4: Yes, `nasm -fwin64` can create a standard `.obj` which you can link into a PE32+ .exe using a linker.  The OP has chosen not to do that.  As far as any more Windows-specific stuff like which exact DLLs are needed for which function, I don't know; presumably the whole rest of the code is full of bugs and other incompletely ported stuff, given that it's naively pushing args in 64-bit code.

Comment: @paulsm4 as it is custom generated it is built by nasm -fbin not linked. If succeeded I will load 64 bit versions. I am loading both, Kernel32.dll and User32dll

Comment: @PeterCordes Actually it is a simple program. In this question i need to fix Import tables. Windows X64 can pass through stack too.

Comment: @user2426998: Yes, but only for the 5th and later arg.  Read the calling convention docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2019

Comment: @PeterCordes yes but that doesn't change anything. This error still occurs

Comment: Of course fixing the buggy asm doesn't change anything if you have other bugs that prevent any of it from running in the first place.  You need to fix both eventually if you want the program to actually work instead of crashing in a different way once you fix the DLL problem.

Comment: @user2426998: Don't edit answers into the question, post them below the question as an answer.  That way you can even mark your own answer "accepted".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjustment needed in function assignment part. Instead of double words quad words should be used.

```
IAT_kernel32:
    ExitProcess:      dq RVA(H_ExitProcess)
    GetStdHandle:     dq RVA(H_GetStdHandle)
    WriteConsoleA:    dq RVA(H_WriteConsoleA)
    dq 0
IAT_user32:
    MessageBoxA:      dq RVA(H_MessageBoxA)
    dq 0
```

Alignments should be corrected according to this example

```
                    align 16, db 0
N_kernel32:         db "kernel32.dll",0
                    align 16, db 0
N_user32:           db "user32.dll",0
                    align 8, db 0
H_ExitProcess:      db 0,0,"ExitProcess",0
                    align 8, db 0
H_GetStdHandle:     db 0,0,"GetStdHandle",0
                    align 8, db 0
H_WriteConsoleA:    db 0,0,"WriteConsoleA",0
                    align 8, db 0
H_MessageBoxA:      db 0,0,"MessageBoxA",0
```

Answer (score 0):

You've clearly got bigger problems than loading the wrong .dll.

SUGGESTIONS:

1. Please update your post and explain what you're trying to do.

   What is this project's goal?

   Not "build a program using custom PE32+ executable".  *WHY* exactly do you need "a custom PE32+ executable" (vs., for example, just recompiling your old .c/.cpp program for 64-bit)?  What code/binary are you starting out from?  What needs to be "different" about your PE32+ image from any "ordinary" 64 bit Windows .exe?  Is a 64 bit Windows .exe actually your goal?  Or do you need to accomplish "something else"?
2. I assume you have Microsoft Visual Studio.

   Use it to as great an extent as possible: if you *can* do something in MSVS, then you probably *should* do it in MSVS. It will make your life much, much easier :)
3. *Definitely* code up some .c "test modules", and build then build them in MSVS with "/Fa". This will give you a "template" for writing your own assembly code, manually. In particular, it will show you how to pass parameters correctly :)
4. *Definitely* make use of MSVS tools like [dumpbin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=vs-2019) or 3rd party tools like [PE Internals](http://www.andreybazhan.com/pe-internals.html).  Compare and contrast "your code" with "other, working examples".